# setAlternateIconName() not changing notification icons and setting icons

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, appicon

I am currently trying to change the icon of my app, but when I'm changing the icon of the app the notification icon and setting icons. Is there something wrong with the way i have provided the images?

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("Black")
```

I get this error when running the line above.

(`reHydrate[21706:7792443] [default] +[LSApplicationProxy applicationProxyFor*] is not a supported method for getting the LSApplicationProxy for the current process, use +[LSBundleProxy bundleProxyForCurrentProcess] instead.`)

Could this be because i don't provide all the necessary images?
here is an example of the images i have added:

-Black@1x.png size 40x40

-Black@2x.png size 80x80

-Black@3x.png size 120x120

Comment: im facing the same problem, it worked a month ago when I tried , but doesn't work now at all